# how to fill datagrid view particular column using dataset i

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a dataset. I am trying to fill values from my data set to my gridview like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTvQd.png

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UnclosedTransactionfetch", con.connect);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid;
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(ds);
DgvUnclosed.Columns("Carid").Name = ds.Tables(0).Columns(0).ToString();
```

But My datagrid view is not filling....what is wrong with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make columns for only desired columns, 
and bind it with source, it will bind only the columns that you have mention in your gridview structure

also make autogeneratecolumns as false

IN window form

give data property name for only the fields you want, rest leave blank

[image]

output

[image]

Comment: actully in gridview i mentioned some column name..i want to get some data from data source to particular column only,that s y i given code like that...but tha particular column not filling..how i can fill that?

Comment: do you mean, like you have given 4 columns name and want to fill data of 2 columns only

Comment: so if you using template field and binding with eval, dont give for those columns and if you binding through boundfield dont give datakey field

Comment: simple way is , use template field give header name in header template or in template field only , and in item template use <<asp:lable id ="lbl1" text = "" runat="server" />

Comment: and for the columns you want to bind data use Eval statement

Comment: OH, then try to leave data property name blank

Comment: Yes i Tried that, give data property name for only the fields you want, rest leave blank

Answer (score 0):

try the follow my friend:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UnclosedTransactionfetch", con.connect);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid;
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(ds);
DgvUnclosed.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; //In this part the dataset pass all fields to the gridview
```

if you need filter some columns add the next lines of code:

```
DgvUnclosed.Columns["CarlID"].Visible = false;
```